# Quick Look Window - Pause video shortcut

Tags: mac, video, quicktime, quicklook

Is there any keyboard shortcut to pause the video, that is being played in Quick Look Window ?

Quick Look Window launches when we click `space bar` on file (say a video file)

I can find the pause button at bottom left of Quick Look Window, but i have to use mouse to pause the video.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `pause` button is on Touchbar.

[image: PauseButton]

ps: I upgraded to a Touchbar Mac and no longer use the old one.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can simply press this key on keyboard. Press again and video will resume.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone arrives here wanting an easy way to take a screengrab of an exact frame, a trick is the pause the video first, then use two-finger swipe to scroll through the frames until you find the one you want.